# jQuery not firing in app but works in console

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a simple button to hide the sidebar navigation in my application.

I have this HTML here.

```
<h3>
  <a href="#" id="sidebar-toggle"><i class="material-icons">face</i></a>
  <span class="text-semibold">Dashboard
</h3>
```

And in my `application.js`

```
$('#sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.sidebar-main').toggle();
});
```

I have the jQuery gem installed in my application.

I added this code to the console in Chrome and it works just fine. However if I click the button without the code in the console it does not work.

I tried replacing the sidebar-main toggle with a `console.log` and it did not trigger it either. Any ideas on why this would not be working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ensuring the DOM is ready prior to running the code, for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidebar-main').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the click event in $( document ).ready() function.
It will ensure the DOM is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Follow this link for help:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/